# Safari + table + width issues

Tags: html, css, safari, html-table, width

I have a table currently containing the main layout of my website found on (http://www.enl-esports.com ).

The table column with id "menu" has a specified width of 150px, yet it randomly decides to become 160px in safari. I have no padding, nor a margin and the problem still occurs when I remove its inner HTML (which might be forcing it to become bigger..). It works fine in Chrome.

I have tried using a fixed table-layout (as found here: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/tables.html#width-layout) which did not fix the problem.

The page you can mostly see this is found here: http://www.enl-esports.com/seasons/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking this might have something to do with the lists bug in safari where margins/paddings which weren't set to 0 can indent the items but it wasn't that.

What I did discorev is that your html is grossly invalid. For instance the only elements allowed as children in an unordered list are list items (`li`) but in that menu you have an anchor as a direct child of the unordered list.

Non-valid html can always result in funky behaviour across different platforms/browsers, I suspect this is one of them.

Then theres the problem of using a table layout which are so last century you should probably be ashamed of it (there is no good reason you should be using one in this layout regardless).

Anyway, to start fixing your problems take a look here and go down the list resolving them:

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=www.enl-esports.com

Comment: I normally never use tables.. the problem is that I needed to in order to get my layout working properly. Since I changed the layout a lot I might be able to revert back, so I'll keep that in mind.. ( Why I needed tables? Because of the artwork and CSS not allowing several items with a min-height of 100% ).

Comment: the problem is, that I have a second menu I'd like to animate in ( the td with id secondMenu ) when a certain button is pressed. While writing this comment a lightbulb flipped on in my head and now Iam going to try something which maybe could fix my problems without using a table.

Comment: @AntwanvanHoudt Since you're using js anyways you could set the width of the right content area with js to w/e you want and then size the columns inside the content area to `33%` with `0.5%` padding on the container with `box-sizing: border-box;` and `position: relative;` don't forget you have to deal with window resizing and you'll have a fairly nifty dynamic page.

Comment: I always try to avoid using JS for the actual layout ( not so much for added functionality, like my dropdown login field )